# Show the cases with all components status deleted, archived, reported

Tags: mysql, sql

I have case table and case_components table I want to get all the cases those components have status deleted, delivered and archived.

```
SELECT
    case_components.case_id,
    case_components.component_id,
    case_components.status 
FROM case_components
LEFT JOIN cases ON case_components.case_id = cases.id
WHERE cases.is_triaged='0'
  AND cases.status NOT IN (12, 10, 89, 104)
  AND case_components.status IN (23, 100, 81)
  AND case_components.delivered_date IS NOT NULL
```

The question is how I can get the cases those component status is IN (23, 100, 81) and it should not select the other cases.

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: The published code is syntactically correct and will 'work' as coded - you need to clarify what problem you are having.

Comment: Your query is getting cases whose components have *any* of the three statuses. Do you want to find only those cases whose components have *all* three statuses? Providing us with some sample data and matches would help.

Comment: Why are you using a left join?